# How to reuse permutation-orderings within scipy's SuperLU-wrapper?

Tags: python, sparse-matrix, scipy

i'm solving sparse linear equations within **scipy 0.18** which internally resorts to **SuperLU** (after umfpack got removed due to license-issues).

Current, i'm doing a complete re-factorization in each iteration of my algorithm, but now i **want to re-use the permutation-ordering** (at least the column-permutation; but maybe even row-permutation) calculated in the first iteration.
How can i achieve this in a nice way using scipy?

I got no previous usage-history of SuperLU (and also not much practical experience with sparse-algebra packages), but the [user-guide](http://crd-legacy.lbl.gov/~xiaoye/SuperLU/ug.pdf) makes me believe, that this should be done through the `options-parameter`.

> Fact
>   Specifies whether or not the factored form of the matrix A is supplied on entry, and if not,
>   how the matrix A will be factorized base on the previous history, such as factor from scratch,
>   reuse Pc and/or Pr, or reuse the data structures of L and U. fact can be one of:
>
> – DOFACT: the matrix A will be factorized from scratch.
>
> – SamePattern: the matrix A will be factorized assuming that a factorization of a matrix
>   with the same sparsity pattern was performed prior to this one. Therefore, this
>   factorization will reuse column permutation vector perm c.
>
> – SampPattern SameRowPerm: the matrix A will be factorized assuming that a factorization
>   of a matrix with the same sparsity pattern and similar numerical values was performed
>   prior to this one. Therefore, this factorization will reuse both row and column
>   permutation vectors perm r and perm c, both row and column scaling factors Dr and
>   Dc, and the distributed data structure set up from the previous symbolic factorization

As an alternative, there is also the following within `options`:

> ColPerm
>   Specifies how to permute the columns of the matrix for sparsity preservation.
>
> – NATURAL: natural ordering.
>
> – MMD ATA: minimum degree ordering on the structure of AT A.
>
> – MMD AT PLUS A: minimum degree ordering on the structure of AT + A.
>
> – COLAMD: approximate minimum degree column ordering
>
> – MY PERMC: use the ordering given in perm c input by the user.

### Questions

- Which part of SuperLU should i use to achieve my goal? One of the above? Something else?
- How can it be done within scipy?

  - The `ColPerm`-parameter is missing `MY_PERMC` in scipy's [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.splu.html#scipy.sparse.linalg.splu) (maybe it's not usable)

Comment: Just came across your post since I wanted to do the same thing. In looking through the source, it is clear that perm_c perm_r can't be set beforehand through the interface. The changes in the C interface would be minorish to get it to work in case you need it bad.